# How to sum event durations in period buckets?

Tags: pandas, time, period

Sample data

```
data = [('2020-06-23 13:43', '2020-06-24 06:43'),
        ('2020-06-23 18:30', '2020-06-24 11:30'),
        ('2020-06-23 14:57', '2020-06-24 07:07'),
        ('2020-06-23 16:37', '2020-06-24 09:03'),
        ('2020-06-23 21:25', '2020-06-24 12:54')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['start', 'end'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.period_range(start='2020-06-23 13:00', end='2020-06-24 12:00', freq='H'))
```

I want to count parallel events. My desired output is percentages like this:

```
                   p0   p1   p2   p3   p4   p5   m0   m1   m2   m3   m4   m5
2020-06-23 13:00 71,7 28,3  0,0  0,0  0,0  0,0   43   17    0    0    0    0
2020-06-23 14:00  0,0 95,0  5,0  0,0  0,0  0,0    0   57    3    0    0    0
...
2020-06-23 21:00  0,0  0,0  0,0  0,0 41,7 58,3    0    0    0    0   25   35
...
2020-06-24 12:00 10,0 90,0  0,0  0,0  0,0  0,0    6   54    0    0    0    0
```

(m0 to m5 are intermediate results in minutes, I would need p0 to p5 as percentages).

I don't know how to start, but surely Pandas has some nice functions to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a working solution myself:

```
import pandas as pd

# interval to analyze
start = pd.Timestamp('2020-06-23 16:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2020-06-24 10:00')

# events
data = [('2020-06-23 13:43', '2020-06-24 06:43'),
        ('2020-06-23 18:30', '2020-06-24 11:30'),
        ('2020-06-23 14:57', '2020-06-24 07:07'),
        ('2020-06-23 16:37', '2020-06-24 09:03'),
        ('2020-06-23 21:25', '2020-06-24 12:54')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['start', 'end'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# evaluation
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        time=pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='H'),
        change=0))

df2 = df2.append([
        pd.DataFrame(dict(time=df1.start, change=1)),
        pd.DataFrame(dict(time=df1.end, change=-1))]) \
        .sort_values('time')

df2['nevents'] = df2.change.cumsum()
df2['delta'] = df2.time.shift(-1) - df2.time
df2['percent'] = df2.delta.dt.total_seconds() / 3600.0

df2['interval'] = df2.time.dt.floor('H')
df2 = df2[(df2.interval >= start) & (df2.interval < end)]

df2 = df2.groupby(['interval', 'nevents']).percent.sum()
df2 = df2.unstack(fill_value=0)
```

I would love to see improvements.